# How to observe a method (from another component) inside the `mat-datepicker`

Tags: angular

I use `mat-datepicker` in the component:

html:

```html
<input
  [(ngModel)]="date.from"
  [matDatepicker]="picker"
  [value]="fDate.value"
  formControlName="dateFrom" 
  id="dateFrom"
  matInput
  name="dateFrom"
  required
>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="picker" matSuffix></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker [calendarComponent]='calendarButtons'></mat-datepicker>
```

ts:

```js
export class TempComponent implements OnInit {
  calendarButtons = CalendarButtonsComponent;
  // ...
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fDate = new FormControl(moment());
    this.date = {
      from: this.fDate.value,
    }
  }
}
```

In the `CalendarButtonsComponent` component I have the `clean` method

html:

```html
  <mat-icon (click)="nextClicked('month')">keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon>
  <mat-icon (click)="clean($event)">close</mat-icon>
```

ts:

```js
export class CalendarButtonsComponent<D> implements OnDestroy {
  @Output() eventEmitter = new EventEmitter<string>();
  private _destroyed = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    private _calendar: MatCalendar<D>,
    private _dateAdapter: DateAdapter<D>,
    @Inject(MAT_DATE_FORMATS) private _dateFormats: MatDateFormats,
    cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {
    _calendar.stateChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed))
      .subscribe(() => cdr.markForCheck());
  }

  get periodLabel() {
    return this._dateAdapter
      .format(
        this._calendar.activeDate,
        this._dateFormats.display.monthYearLabel
      )
      .toLocaleUpperCase();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._destroyed.next();
    this._destroyed.complete();
  } 

  nextClicked(mode: 'month' | 'year') { 
    this._calendar.activeDate = mode === 'month'
      ? this._dateAdapter.addCalendarMonths(this._calendar.activeDate, 1)
      : this._dateAdapter.addCalendarYears(this._calendar.activeDate, 1);
  }

  clean() { 
  }  
}
```

I would like to use the `clean` method to clean the date.from model. The model ( `this.date.from` ) is in the `TempComponent` component.

I don't know how the event emitted in the `CalendarButtonsComponent` component was listened to in the `TempComponent` component.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

use an output...

in calendar button component:

```
@Output() onClean = new EventEmitter<void>();

clean() { this.onClean.next(); }
```

then in the parent template:

```
<calendar-buttons (onClean)="fDate.reset()"></calendar-buttons>
```

Comment: It adds the component in this way `<mat-datepicker #picker [calendarComponent]='calendarButtons'></mat-datepicker>` I don't know how to use the method here

Comment: As he adds in this way: `<mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="picker" matSuffix>
                </mat-datepicker-toggle> <mat-datepicker #picker [calendarComponent]='calendarButtons'><app-calendar-buttons (onClean)="fDate.reset()"> </app-calendar-buttons> </mat-datepicker>` I get an error message `Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CalendarButtonsComponent -> MatCalendar]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CalendarButtonsComponent -> MatCalendar]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MatCalendar!`

Comment: someone will help

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api There is no calendarComponent input in the Material date picker api

Comment: which method to use to assign `date.from = null` ?

Comment: how to use the `close` method to assign to the object: `date.from = null` object